# Trouble with jquery validate when using on checkboxes

Tags: jquery-validate

I am trying to use jquery validate to validate the form and I want the user to select atleast 1 checkbox. The reason for having different names is that they match with the database field names.

```
....
<input class="myclass" type="checkbox" name="option_1">Option 1<br>
<input class="myclass" type="checkbox" name="option_2">Option 2<br>
<input class="myclass" type="checkbox" name="option_3">Option 3<br>
<input class="myclass" type="checkbox" name="option_4">Option 4<br>
<input class="myclass" type="checkbox" name="option_5">Option 5<br>
....
```

Here is my jQuery code used for validation:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("require_from_group", function(value, element, options) {
    var valid = $(options[1], element.form).filter(function() {
        return $(this).val(); 
    }).length >= options[0];

    if(!$(element).data('reval')) {
        var fields = $(options[1], element.form);
        fields.data('reval', true).valid();
        fields.data('reval', false);
    }
    return valid;
}, jQuery.format("Please fill out at least {0} of these fields."));


$("#formname").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form){
        console.log("Came here");
        return false;
    },
    rules:{
        option_1:{ require_from_group: [1, '.myclass']},
        option_2:{ require_from_group: [1, '.myclass']},
        option_3:{ require_from_group: [1, '.myclass']},
        option_4:{ require_from_group: [1, '.myclass']},
        option_5:{ require_from_group: [1, '.myclass']}
    }
});
```

This code is not working. Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Thanks! @Sparky, I think the code for require_from_group in the additional_methods.js was better. Everything now works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't see anything wrong inside your `.validate()` code or in your HTML markup. But I did not check your `require_from_group` method because you did not need to write this from scratch.

AFAIK, The latest version of the plugin (1.11.1) fixed the bugs in this method. You only have to include [the additional-methods.js file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js) and it should work as expected.